# Visual Basic Arrays - Execute string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have created an array of 10 strings. Saved as holding for temporary purposes. However I need a way of executing the string I have created. I am simply trying to execute the command `picturebox1.hide()` without typing it out 10 consecutive times, by changing the number following the picturebox.
Many Thanks, 
Alex Currie

```
Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Holding(10) As String
    For n = 1 To 10
        Holding(n) = "picturebox" & n & ".hide"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please use only applicable tags - your question is not about VB6 or VBA

Comment: This is a very poor way to accomplish the given task.  You should instead loop through the controls, check if the given control is a picturebox, and then hide it.

Comment: You cant put code into a string variable (or array thereof) and execute it.  String are variables.

Comment: @LukePark How would I create a loop though the commands. Would this require an if statement within a for loop? an example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please see the answer I have posted.  This is how I would solve the problem.  This assumes that all of your pictureboxes are in one panel or window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through all of the controls in a form (or Container, e.g. Panel), check if they are a PictureBox and then hide them like so:

```
For Each x As Control In panel1.Controls
    If TypeOf x Is PictureBox Then
        x.Hide()
    End If
Next
```

Forgive me if I've made a silly mistake, Visual Basic is something I haven't used in a long time.

Comment: Many Thanks Luke with a bit of tweaking this worked perfectly.

Comment: Not a problem, might also be a good idea to modify your question title to help future viewers.  "How to hide all pictureboxes on a form?" or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Are you just trying to hide all of your picture boxes?

Instead of an array of strings, why not an array of picture boxes?

```
Dim PictureBoxes = New PictureBox() {picturebox1, picturebox2, ... }

For n = 1 to 10
    PictureBoxes(n).hide
Next
```